# How to make sure a systemd service start after network fully connected?

Tags: systemd, systemd-networkd

System

- Hardware: RPi 4
- OS: Manjaro Arm
- Network app: systemd-networkd

I feel like I've done everything to ensure my testbot will be called once network connection is established and yet I still receive lookup address information failure errors.

*Network daemon wait online status*

```
$ sudo systemctl is-enabled systemd-networkd-wait-online
enabled
```

*Network configuration*

```
$ cat 20-wired.network 
[Match]
Name=enp1s0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv6
```

*testbot.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=Test bot
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Environment="PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin/:/bin" "TZ=CEST"
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/testbot
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Restart=always
User=folaht
SyslogIdentifier=testbot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

*System journal*

```
$ sudo journalctl -u testbot
...
jui 15 08:11:14 Klav testbot[272] Error: Io(Custom { kind: Other, error: "failed to lookup address information: Temporary failure in name resolution" })
...
```

*Daemon status*

```
$ sudo systemctl status testbot
[sudo] Mot de passe de folaht : 
● testbot.service - Test bot.
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/testbot.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-05-24 13:55:51 CEST; 1min 16s ago
    Process: 272 ExecStart=/usr/bin/testbot (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 272 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

mai 24 13:55:51 Klav systemd[1]: testbot.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
mai 24 13:55:51 Klav systemd[1]: Stopped Test bot..
mai 24 13:55:51 Klav systemd[1]: testbot.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
mai 24 13:55:51 Klav systemd[1]: test.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
mai 24 13:55:51 Klav systemd[1]: Failed to start Test bot..
```

[edit]

I recently changed `Name=enp1s0` to `Name=eth0` and it seems to work.